# Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('..') does not match the recipient window's origin ('')

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small application(localhost:55777) window containing a button. I am opening this application as a pop up in another application(localhost:3214).

I want the pop up(hosted at localhost:3214) to be closed on the click of the above button hosted at (localhost:55777). For this I am using window.postMessage() and handling the message event thru addListener.

The full code goes here :

Application 1(Sender)  http://localhost:55777:

```
<button id="closeme" onclick="closeParent()">Close Parent</button>
```

JS:

```
function closeParent() {    

window.postMessage("closePopUp", "http://localhost:3214");


return false;
```

}

Application 2(Receiver): http://localhost:3214

JS:

```
 function receiveMessage(event) {
    if (event.data == 'close') {
        alert("Message received");
    }
}
addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
```

Now the receiver side never get the method hit when the postMessage is called. Getting error :

> Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('http://localhost:3214') does not match the recipient window's origin ('http://localhost:55777').

Can somebody please suggest a work around for this. I am using jquery with type script.

Comment: Did you ever mange to fix this? I have the same issue now.